# Writing an expression containing the comparison operator "=" as a subroutine argument

Tags: vba, excel

I have a subroutine in Excel VBA that takes a Boolean value as input.  The Boolean value should be `True` if the value of a cell is equal to "Yes", and `False` otherwise.

I already know I should be able to do something like this:

```
Dim C as boolean
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Yes" Then
C = True
End If
dostuff(C)
```

But I would prefer to be more concise.  I want to do something like this:

```
dostuff(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")="Yes")
```

I basically want to make sure that the statement is evaluated as a logical expression and not an assignment.

Will this work as it is?
If not, what is the best / correct way of doing this without having to use an if statement?

Comment: Why are you against breaking out the if statement as a function?

Comment: Exactly how you posted it: `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Yes"` -> should show False (or True)

Comment: @findwindow Because it's an "if true return true else return false" pattern in disguise :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB, `=` is *only* an assignment when it appears as the token of an [AssignmentStatements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711981(v=vs.71).aspx) or in a declaration with an assignment. (The link is for VB.NET, but it applies well-enough to VBA here.)

In all other cases - whenever `=` appears in an *expression* (or a sub-expression) - it is always treated as the comparison equality operator and yields a boolean value.

In the post it is found in an *expression* used as an argument to the function; and as such it will work as desired. Different coding guidelines may prohibit such, but those are irrelevant to the semantics.

These grammar rules also explains why one can't "chain assignments" in VB.

---

Thus it works as desired:

```
 dostuff(ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Yes")
'[-- function call ---------------------]
'        [-- expression ---------------]
'                                ^-- '=' as comparison
```

Another way to write the code, if one didn't like comparisons in arguments:

```
 Dim C as boolean = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Yes"
'[-- declaration with assignment -----------------]
'                 ^-- '=' for assignment
'                   [-- expression ---------------]
'                                           ^-- '=' as comparison
 dostuff(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work. It will be taken as a test, not as an assignment. This is the semantic of the = operator whenever used inside an expression (unlike in C, which has the == operator for disambiguation..)